# GNU screen: Running commands in different window when screen is started

Tags: gnu-screen

The .screenrc file allows the user to specify that they want multiple windows open when screen is first run.  Eg.

```
screen -t myWindowA 0 "" 
screen -t myWindowB 1 "-${SHELL}" 
screen -t myWindowC 2 "-${SHELL}"
```

What I would like is for each window to run some commands first, like:

```
screen -t myWindowA 0 "<go to directory a, source a.sh" 
screen -t myWindowB 1 "-${SHELL} <go to directory b, source b.sh>" 
screen -t myWindowC 2 "-${SHELL} <go to directoy c; start a watch on `ls -l`>"
```

Is there any way to do that?

Note this is similar to, but different from [this issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10186/execute-command-on-gnu-screen-attachment).

Comment: It's a tiny bit off topic, but have you heard of byobu? It's screen, but a bit easier to use. If so, nevermind. :) If not: https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/byobu.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can. On my servers i have a */etc/screenrc* with:

```
screen -t TOP 0 top
screen -t ETC 1 cd /etc
screen -t Console 2
```

Comment: the first example works great, but I can't seem to get it to work with sourced environments, eg "source env.sh".  I get "Cannot exec 'source': No such file or directory" then "[screen is terminating]".  When I try to "cd" as in your second example, I get the a similar error.

Comment: @Robert Gowland source is a bash builtin, so it can't be executed by scree... Your best option, IMHO, is to create some bash scripts and execute them instead.

Comment: cool.  Thanks for helping me understand what will and won't work.